# How to set the Value variable of this custom Odin Inspector class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know, the title is bad, but I couldn't think if a better one. The question is very specific.

Ok, so I'm using a class in my game identical to Odin Inspector's example RPG Skills classes. But it's set up in a way I don't quite understand and I can't work out how to *set* the value (I can *get* it, and there is a *setter*, so it's possible to set too). Also, all the skill classes/structs/etc are in the same .cs file.

The SkillList function I use to get the Value:
(I get it with `skills[Strength].Value;` in other classes)

```
public int this[SkillType type]
{
    get
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.skills.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.skills[i].Type == type)
                return this.skills[i].Value;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.skills.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.skills[i].Type == type)
            {
                var val = this.skills[i];
                val.Value = value;
                this.skills[i] = val;
                return;
            }
        }
        this.skills.Add(new SkillValue(type, value));
    }
}
```

SkillValue struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SkillValue : IEquatable<SkillValue>
{
    public SkillType Type;
    public int Value;

    public SkillValue(SkillType type, int value)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public SkillValue(SkillType type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Value = 0;
    }

    public bool Equals(SkillValue other)
    { return this.Type == other.Type && this.Value == other.Value; }
}
```

SkillType enum:

```
public enum SkillType
{
    Science,
    Technology,
    Arts,
    Language,
}
```

I've tried:

`skills[Science].Value = 10;`

`skills[Science] = new SkillValue(Science, 10);`

`skills[Science, 10];` (using a new function made by me)

`skills[Science](10);`

`skills[Science].Value(10);`

`skills[Science] = 10;`

But none work, and I'm just guessing randomly now.
How can I set the value?
Thanks

---

The solution:
`character.skills[Rorschach.Character.Skills.SkillType.Science] = value;`

Comment: Since it is an enum, shouldn't you write `skills[SkillType.Science].Value`?

Comment: @MaxPlay I don't really know the correct syntax, but that doesn't work. And I have included the appropriate usings in the class that has a SkillList variable. It works as I wrote above to get it, just not to set it.

Comment: This sounds and your code looks like you should simply rather use a `Dictionary<SkillType, int> skills` instead

Comment: @derHugo I'd like to keep using this if possible, since it's used in a number of area of my game. Plus, since the Odin devs included a setter, I assume it is capable of setting the value in some way. I just haven't worked with any ```public Type this[parameter]```-style calls before.

Comment: Could you please show us the entire class? What does `this` refer to?

Comment: Can you view this: https://pastebin.com/RtuFx1dL

Comment: @Spectralle this helps a lot. Now please also add the code of how exactly you are trying to use this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is of type `int` and expects a key of type `SkillType` so it should probably be

```
SkillList skills;

skills[SkillType.Science] = 10;
```

actually also

> I get it with `skills[Strength].Value;`

seems odd with the code you provided. As said the property returns an `int` which has no property `Value` so it should actually be

```
int x = skills[SkillType.Strength];
```

---

Now knowing the full implementation code and your actual usage:

> ```
> public SkillList skills;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> public int Science 
> { 
>     get { return this.Character.skills[Science].Value; } 
>     set { this.Character.skills[Science].Value(10); }
> }
> ```

**ATTENTION!**

What you did here by accident is using the other property

```
public SkillValue this[int index]
{
    get { return this.skills[index]; }
    set { this.skills[index] = value; }
}
```

which takes an `int` index and returns a `SkillValue`.

**BUT** you are causing a runtime `StackOverlowExeption` due to a recursive call of `Science`.

You can't use `Science` inside of the getter or setter of equally called property!

Imagine using the getter as example:

- You would call

  ```
  var test = Science;
  ```
- so it executes the getter

  ```
  return Character.skills[Science].Value;
  ```
- but well ... in order to know the value of `Science` in order to use it here as the index it would again have to execute the getter so again

  ```
  return Character.skills[Science].Value;
  ```

and by now you hopefully get what I mean.

#### Solution

You property should actually as guessed before rather look like

```
public int Science 
{ 
    get { return Character.skills[SkillType.Science]; } 
    set { Character.skills[SkillType.Science] = value; }
}
```

Comment: "skills[Strength]" is a variable of type "SkillValue", not int, unless I'm misunderstanding something. The struct SkillValue contains an int variable called "Value" which holds the value.

Comment: something like `skills[Strength]` wouldn't even exist but `skills[SkillType.Strength]` ... and well without seeing of what type `skills` is exactly it is hard to tell ... all I can say is that your property `int this[SkillType type]` is of type `int` so it returns and expects an `int` as value and a `SkillType` as indexer/key

Comment: "skills" is a SkillList variable. Similar to an array I believe, in that it uses a SkillType or an int to identify a specific SkillValue in the SkillList. Thanks for the information. I have no idea how its functional now then, but I guess I'll keep playing around and trying stuff ;P

Comment: And the declaration: ```public SkillList skills;```
And the usage: ```public int Science { get { return this.Character.skills[Science].Value; } set { this.character.skills[Science].Value(10);```

Comment: @Spectralle **wait**! this is a recursive call to `Science` and will cause a **StackOverflowException**!! You can't use `Science` within the getter or setter of equally called property!

Comment: Can't say I completely understand all that, but I get that its bad. Does it make any difference that it is in ```#if UNITY_EDITOR``` and runs only in an editor window? It hasn't seemed to cause any errors so far...

Comment: @Spectralle please see the updated answer! I tried to explain it in more detail there

Comment: 1 Unity crash later and it works perfectly, haha. Thanks for your help :)